# SQL list all categories and products (SKUs) in category

Tags: magento-1.9, database, sql

guys ! 
How can i list all categories with related products in them (i need the SKUs). Where is the relation table for catalog_category_entity(or varchar) and catalog_product_entity(or varchar). ?

I can use only SQL.. because i don't know php. Thx !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category product relation table is `catalog_category_product`. It contains the category id and the product id its related to. Also there is the position column `position` which determines the order in which the products are fetched.

So to get the product SKU you need do a join with the `catalog_product_entity` which has the SKU's for the products.

So something like

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    `catalog_category_product` `ccp` 
JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity` as `cpe` 
        ON `cpe`.entity_id = `ccp`.`product_id`
```

should help you get the SKU's against the product ids. And of course you can replace the `SELECT *` with only the fields you like to have.

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 3):

Here is mysql Query to Fetch All products with their categories from magento 1.9

```
SELECT product_id,product_name,product_path, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(category_id)) AS category_ids,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(category_name)) AS category_name,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(path)) AS category_path FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT B.*,cpev.`value` AS product_path FROM   (SELECT A.*,cv.value AS `category_name`,cc1.value AS path  FROM (
        SELECT
            catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id AS product_id,
            catalog_product_entity_varchar.`value` AS product_name,
            catalog_product_entity.sku,
            `at_category_id`.`category_id`
        FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
        INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
        LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=catalog_product_entity.entity_id)
        WHERE catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_type_id = (
            SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product' )
        AND catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id = (
            SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (
            SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product' ))
    ) AS A
    INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity` AS cat ON cat.`entity_id` = A.category_id
    JOIN `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS cv ON cat.entity_id = cv.`entity_id`
    JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cc1 ON cv.entity_id=cc1.entity_id 
    JOIN `eav_attribute` AS att ON att.`attribute_id` = cv.`attribute_id`
    JOIN `eav_entity_type` AS aty ON att.`entity_type_id` = aty.`entity_type_id`
    WHERE aty.`entity_model` = 'catalog/category' AND att.`attribute_code` = 'name' AND cc1.attribute_id IN (SELECT attribute_id AS attr FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code='url_path')
) AS B
JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev ON cpev.`entity_id` = B.product_id
WHERE cpev.`attribute_id` IN (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'url_key')) sub_query GROUP BY product_id
```

Hope this will help you to fetch all products with their categories using mysql query.

Comment: dude. Awesome but its a hell of a query ;)

Answer (score 2):

Best and easy way to fetch sku's based on the category id from sql.To help anyone looking for an answer that works with Magento 2. x

```
SELECT product.entity_id as product_id, product.sku FROM catalog_product_entity as product
    INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as cat_prod on product.entity_id = cat_prod.product_id
    WHERE cat_prod.category_id=YOUR Category ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is MySQL Query to fetch all products with their categories by sub-query

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id` As `product_id`,`e`.`type_id` As product_type, `e`.`sku`,(Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cv.value)) FROM `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS cv ,catalog_category_product  AS `at_category_id` where at_category_id.category_id = cv.`row_id`
 AND (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id) and cv.attribute_id = 41 and cv.store_id = 0 
 ) AS category_name FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`;
```

This will help you to fetch all products with their categories.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone looking for an answer that works with Magento 2.1.6 (and probably other 2. x versions, but untested), Vikas answer above was great, and all I had to do was change the cv.attribute_id from 41 to 33. This gave me the actual name of a category that I wanted to fetch against the SKU. You can check your database table (catalog_category_entity_varchar) for this info in the attribute_id column.

The final code I used successfully is as follows:

```
SELECT  e.entity_id As product_id,
        e.sku,
        (Select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cv.value)) 
            FROM    catalog_category_entity_varchar AS cv ,
                    catalog_category_product AS at_category_id 
            WHERE   at_category_id.category_id = cv.entity_id AND 
                    (at_category_id.product_id=e.entity_id) AND 
                    cv.attribute_id = 33 and 
                    cv.store_id = 0 ) 
        AS category_name
FROM catalog_product_entity AS e;
```

This results in a single row for a Product ID, SKU and a single column of comma separated values of all Categories that SKU is linked to.